# How to make an image (of a rope) "swing" back and forth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to make a long vertical image 'swing' - I want to use an image of a rope with a small subtle swing back and forth in an area of my site, for a neat background animation that themes with the site.

Is this possible with JS/jQuery. (Not into Flash)

Comment: I never thought I'd say this, but that sounds like the perfect candidate for a GIF.

Comment: sure it is possible but the code depend very much on the images but in our modern world we can also do this with css3 or html5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at this http://jsfiddle.net/FBcFb/

forgot to reference this i got this code from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Animate_a_pendulum#JavaScript_.2B_.3Ccanvas.3E)

Comment: Quite nifty: a little friction would be interesting :) Works Here (FF8). How is support for using an image on a canvas?

Comment: look at this for using images on a canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: I wrote that code and published it on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Animate_a_pendulum). Please attribute it.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with CSS transformations, and in your case rotations, you can find the syntax in [this page](http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate). You will need a bit of Javascript to slightly alter the angle of the rotation on a regular basis. It won't work on IE<9, though...

Comment: I imagine the rope "segments" would also need to be split up.

Comment: Why not, but there's an order of magnitude in complexity between a straight rope swinging and a "real" fluid rope with multiple segments. Anyway, both can be achieved with CSS/JS.

Comment: You can probably produce a decent effect with no JS by making a series of nested elements (so each rope segment is a child of the one above it) and CSS-animating them all.